# AMD Radeon GPU only uses 384MB VRAM instead of +2GB dedicated video-memory

Tags: 12.04, wine, playonlinux, winetricks

for some reason a majority if not all games are limited to only 384MBs of video memory (VRAM) instead of it's full 2048MB dedicated memory. I read somewhere that disabling "Sych with VBlank" in the OpenGL menu would resolve this, but it did not. Now what could be the cause of this?

Take note that all 3D-applications tested have been run with Wine 1.5.26, PlayOnLinux 4.0.14 with AMD Catalyst 13.1, 13.2 and 13.3-beta3 will crash at random stating that there's **not enough video memory** or that an **applications error** has accord, which make my first impression of Ubuntu extremely unproductive, limited and most important unplayable.

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on write access to 0x00000000 in 32-bit code (0x018aeb5c).
Register dump:
CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
EIP:018aeb5c ESP:0033f0f8 EBP:00000000 EFLAGS:00010202( R- -- I - - - )
EAX:00007fff EBX:00000000 ECX:0000001c EDX:063f3d36
ESI:2eb88004 EDI:00000001
Stack dump:
0x0033f0f8: 0033f4d4 0072e3f0 0033f304 31a70348
0x0033f108: 02ff0010 c38bf9ec 42934a0d 063f3d36
0x0033f118: 063f3d36 ff3f3d36 ff3f3d36 43dfdec1
0x0033f128: 2eb88054 c38c3821 43dedec1 428f68be
0x0033f138: 063f3d36 000000a8 ff3f3d36 063f3d36
0x0033f148: 000000a8 41f00000 bf7e55f9 bdce5ea0
000c: sel=0067 base=00000000 limit=00000000 16-bit rw-
Backtrace:
=>0 0x018aeb5c in gameclient (+0x14eb5c) (0x00000000)
0x018aeb5c: fsts 0xffffffe4(%ecx)
Modules:
Module Address Debug info Name (144 modules)
PE 340000- 355000 Deferred gamedatabase
PE 360000- 368000 Deferred ltmemory
PE 370000- 377000 Deferred x3daudio1_5
PE 3a0000- 3a7000 Deferred stringeditruntime
PE 400000- 7c6000 Deferred fear2
PE 7d0000- c1a000 Deferred d3dx9_40
PE fe0000- 1028000 Deferred steamclient
PE 1140000- 118b000 Deferred steam
PE 1760000- 1992000 Export gameclient
PE 1aa0000- 1ae3000 Deferred clientfx.fxd
PE 1ed0000- 1f5b000 Deferred xaudio2_3
PE 10000000-10015000 Deferred steam_api
PE 18000000-18033000 Deferred binkw32
ELF 7939e000-79400000 Deferred libatiadlxx.so
ELF 7943f000-7b800000 Deferred fglrx_dri.so
ELF 7b800000-7ba45000 Deferred kernel32<elf>
\-PE 7b810000-7ba45000 \ kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcd9000 Deferred ntdll<elf>
\-PE 7bc10000-7bcd9000 \ ntdll
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000 Deferred <wine-loader>
ELF 7c4bf000-7c522000 Deferred libmpg123.so.0
ELF 7c522000-7c53a000 Deferred libresolv.so.2
ELF 7c53a000-7c542000 Deferred libogg.so.0
ELF 7c542000-7c56d000 Deferred libvorbis.so.0
ELF 7c56d000-7c6e5000 Deferred libvorbisenc.so.2
ELF 7cd4a000-7cd92000 Deferred dsound<elf>
\-PE 7cd50000-7cd92000 \ dsound
ELF 7cd92000-7cde0000 Deferred libflac.so.8
ELF 7cde0000-7ce52000 Deferred libsndfile.so.1
ELF 7ce52000-7ce9b000 Deferred libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7ce9b000-7cf00000 Deferred libpulsecommon-1.1.so
ELF 7d013000-7d029000 Deferred winemp3<elf>
\-PE 7d020000-7d029000 \ winemp3
ELF 7d029000-7d040000 Deferred imaadp32<elf>
\-PE 7d030000-7d040000 \ imaadp32
ELF 7d040000-7d08e000 Deferred libpulse.so.0
ELF 7d08e000-7d095000 Deferred libnss_dns.so.2
ELF 7d095000-7d0aa000 Deferred avrt<elf>
\-PE 7d0a0000-7d0aa000 \ avrt
ELF 7d0aa000-7d0d2000 Deferred winepulse<elf>
\-PE 7d0b0000-7d0d2000 \ winepulse
ELF 7d0d2000-7d0f4000 Deferred mmdevapi<elf>
\-PE 7d0e0000-7d0f4000 \ mmdevapi
ELF 7d434000-7d452000 Deferred libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7d452000-7d46b000 Deferred libatiuki.so.1
ELF 7d46b000-7d557000 Deferred libgl.so.1
ELF 7d562000-7d569000 Deferred libasyncns.so.0
ELF 7d569000-7d573000 Deferred libwrap.so.0
ELF 7d573000-7d63c000 Deferred crypt32<elf>
\-PE 7d580000-7d63c000 \ crypt32
ELF 7d63c000-7d672000 Deferred wintrust<elf>
\-PE 7d640000-7d672000 \ wintrust
ELF 7d672000-7d686000 Deferred psapi<elf>
\-PE 7d680000-7d686000 \ psapi
ELF 7d686000-7d6ee000 Deferred dbghelp<elf>
\-PE 7d690000-7d6ee000 \ dbghelp
ELF 7d72d000-7d735000 Deferred libjson.so.0
ELF 7d74c000-7d782000 Deferred uxtheme<elf>
\-PE 7d750000-7d782000 \ uxtheme
ELF 7d782000-7d7a6000 Deferred imm32<elf>
\-PE 7d790000-7d7a6000 \ imm32
ELF 7d7a6000-7d7ac000 Deferred libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7d7ac000-7d7b7000 Deferred libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7d7b7000-7d7c7000 Deferred libxi.so.6
ELF 7d7c7000-7d7cb000 Deferred libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7d7cb000-7d7d4000 Deferred libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7d7d4000-7d7de000 Deferred libxrender.so.1
ELF 7d7de000-7d7e4000 Deferred libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7d7e4000-7d7e8000 Deferred libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7d7e8000-7d7ef000 Deferred libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7d7ef000-7d7f3000 Deferred libxau.so.6
ELF 7d7f3000-7d814000 Deferred libxcb.so.1
ELF 7d814000-7d81a000 Deferred libuuid.so.1
ELF 7d81a000-7d834000 Deferred libice.so.6
ELF 7d834000-7d968000 Deferred libx11.so.6
ELF 7d968000-7d97a000 Deferred libxext.so.6
ELF 7d97a000-7d983000 Deferred libsm.so.6
ELF 7d99f000-7da32000 Deferred winex11<elf>
\-PE 7d9b0000-7da32000 \ winex11
ELF 7da81000-7daab000 Deferred libexpat.so.1
ELF 7daab000-7dadf000 Deferred libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7dadf000-7daf5000 Deferred libz.so.1
ELF 7daf5000-7db8f000 Deferred libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7dbab000-7dce5000 Deferred oleaut32<elf>
\-PE 7dbc0000-7dce5000 \ oleaut32
ELF 7dce5000-7dded000 Deferred comctl32<elf>
\-PE 7dcf0000-7dded000 \ comctl32
ELF 7dded000-7de65000 Deferred shlwapi<elf>
\-PE 7de00000-7de65000 \ shlwapi
ELF 7de65000-7e093000 Deferred shell32<elf>
\-PE 7de70000-7e093000 \ shell32
ELF 7e093000-7e1a1000 Deferred opengl32<elf>
\-PE 7e0b0000-7e1a1000 \ opengl32
ELF 7e1a1000-7e2da000 Deferred wined3d<elf>
\-PE 7e1b0000-7e2da000 \ wined3d
ELF 7e2da000-7e317000 Deferred d3d9<elf>
\-PE 7e2e0000-7e317000 \ d3d9
ELF 7e317000-7e33d000 Deferred iphlpapi<elf>
\-PE 7e320000-7e33d000 \ iphlpapi
ELF 7e33d000-7e373000 Deferred ws2_32<elf>
\-PE 7e340000-7e373000 \ ws2_32
ELF 7e373000-7e38f000 Deferred wsock32<elf>
\-PE 7e380000-7e38f000 \ wsock32
ELF 7e38f000-7e3ba000 Deferred msacm32<elf>
\-PE 7e390000-7e3ba000 \ msacm32
ELF 7e3ba000-7e470000 Deferred winmm<elf>
\-PE 7e3c0000-7e470000 \ winmm
ELF 7e470000-7e5ae000 Deferred msvcp90<elf>
\-PE 7e4b0000-7e5ae000 \ msvcp90
ELF 7e5ae000-7e650000 Deferred msvcp80<elf>
\-PE 7e5c0000-7e650000 \ msvcp80
ELF 7e650000-7e689000 Deferred msvcr100<elf>
\-PE 7e660000-7e689000 \ msvcr100
ELF 7e689000-7e72f000 Deferred msvcrt<elf>
\-PE 7e6a0000-7e72f000 \ msvcrt
ELF 7e72f000-7e75d000 Deferred msvcr80<elf>
\-PE 7e740000-7e75d000 \ msvcr80
ELF 7e75d000-7e7de000 Deferred rpcrt4<elf>
\-PE 7e770000-7e7de000 \ rpcrt4
ELF 7e7de000-7e919000 Deferred ole32<elf>
\-PE 7e7f0000-7e919000 \ ole32
ELF 7e942000-7e95a000 Deferred wtsapi32<elf>
\-PE 7e950000-7e95a000 \ wtsapi32
ELF 7e95a000-7e9c9000 Deferred advapi32<elf>
\-PE 7e970000-7e9c9000 \ advapi32
ELF 7e9c9000-7eae4000 Deferred gdi32<elf>
\-PE 7e9e0000-7eae4000 \ gdi32
ELF 7eae4000-7ec3e000 Deferred user32<elf>
\-PE 7eb00000-7ec3e000 \ user32
ELF 7ec3e000-7ec58000 Deferred libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ec58000-7ec61000 Deferred libnss_compat.so.2
ELF 7ec63000-7ec7d000 Deferred version<elf>
\-PE 7ec70000-7ec7d000 \ version
ELF 7efaf000-7efdb000 Deferred libm.so.6
ELF 7efdb000-7efe4000 Deferred librt.so.1
ELF 7efe7000-7eff4000 Deferred libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7eff4000-7f000000 Deferred libnss_nis.so.2
PE 7f4a0000-7f81e000 Deferred gameserver
ELF f7473000-f7478000 Deferred libdl.so.2
ELF f7478000-f7622000 Deferred libc.so.6
ELF f7623000-f763e000 Deferred libpthread.so.0
ELF f765a000-f779e000 Dwarf libwine.so.1
ELF f77a0000-f77c2000 Deferred ld-linux.so.2
ELF f77c2000-f77c3000 Deferred [vdso].so
Threads:
process tid prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
0000001f 0
0000001e 0
00000015 0
00000010 0
0000000f 0
00000012 winedevice.exe
0000001c 0
00000019 0
00000014 0
00000013 0
0000001a plugplay.exe
00000020 0
0000001d 0
0000001b 0
00000021 explorer.exe
00000022 0
00000025 (D) C:\Program Files (x86)\Fear2\FEAR2.exe
00000046 0
0000003f 0
0000003e 0
00000032 0
00000031 15
00000030 0
0000002f 15
0000002e 0
0000002d 0
0000002c 15
0000002b 0
0000002a 0
00000029 0
00000028 0
00000027 0
00000026 0 <==
System information:
Wine build: wine-1.5.26
Platform: i386 (WOW64)
Host system: Linux
Host version: 3.5.0-26-generic
```

Is there a solution to this problem? How do I make either Linux or my 3D-applications realize that there's more dedicated video memory available for my HD6970? Are there appropriate commands for this kind of issues, or are there other applications much like Wine/ PlayOnLinux that may utilize my applications and full memory better?

[Ubuntu showing only 256mb of vram when it should be 1GB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248780/ubuntu-showing-only-256mb-of-vram-when-it-should-be-1gb)

[Max VRAM supported by open source ATI radeon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99344/max-vram-supported-by-open-source-ati-radeon)

Thanks in advance
Raklödder

Comment: Steam Big Picture mode reports incorrect low RAM numbers. I believe this this a problem with OpenGL but OpenGL 4.5 fixes this, at least from what I've read. I'm not certain and don't take my word for it. Further research will show this is an extremely common problem. I'm looking into ways to force VRAM size myself just like you can with WINE, but in Linux and any programs that will still need forced VRAM numbers. It's not automatic for AMD users, neither open source nor FGLRX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you determining that the GPU only sees 384MB of VRAM?

It's likely that only programs run in Wine are seeing 384MB of VRAM. This would be because OpenGL doesn't ([yet](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~idr/mesa/log/?h=query-renderer)) provide any way of querying how much VRAM a card has, so Wine is forced to guess; it might be guessing badly for you.

To tell Wine how much VRAM your card actually has, you want to set the `VideoMemorySize` registry key. You can either do this following the steps on the [UsefulRegistryKeys](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:2RxSVGEU9SIJ%3awiki.winehq.org/UsefulRegistryKeys+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au) Wine Wiki page, or run the command `winetricks videomemorysize=2048` at a terminal, which will set the registry key for you.